# Django Import-export TypeError: clean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row'

Tags: django, django-import-export

When importing csv files it deliver the following error. I think this is related to the date widget?

**This is an example of my csv:**

" , ICE, France, EST Current, HD, 4.59, EUR, GROSS, 01/01/08, , test"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 662, in import_row
self.import_obj(instance, row, dry_run)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 516, in import_obj
self.import_field(field, obj, data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 499, in import_field
field.save(obj, data, is_m2m)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 110, in save
cleaned = self.clean(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 66, in clean
value = self.widget.clean(value, row=data)
TypeError: clean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row'
```

**Resource is build like this**
As I said, I can't be sure what is the widget that is raising this error. That's why I paste all the Class here: (I know is too long)

```
class retailResource(ModelResource):
    client = fields.Field(
        column_name='client',
        attribute='client',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Client, 'name')
    )
    country = fields.Field(
        column_name='country',
        attribute='country',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Country, 'name')
    )
    catalogue_type = fields.Field(
        column_name='catalogue_type',
        attribute='catalogue_type',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(CatalogueType, 'name')
    )
    currency_in_report = fields.Field(
        column_name='currency_in_report',
        attribute='currency_in_report',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Currency, 'iso3_code')
    )
    start_date = fields.Field(
        attribute='start_date',
        widget=fields.Field(
            attribute='start_date',
            column_name='start_date',
            widget=widgets.DateWidget('%d/%m/%Y'))
    )
    end_date = fields.Field(
        attribute='end_date',
        widget=widgets.DateWidget('%d/%m/%Y')
    )

    class Meta():
        model = RetailPrice
        fields = ('id','client', 'country', 'catalogue_type','quality','gross_retail_price',
                  'currency_in_report','reported_as','start_date','end_date','comments',)
        export_order = ['id','client', 'country', 'catalogue_type','quality','gross_retail_price',
                  'currency_in_report','reported_as','start_date','end_date','comments']
        import_id_fields = ('id',)
```

**Admin is like this**

```
class retailAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = retailResource
  [...]
```

Comment: Well, I've been able to update a date without using the widget. So now I'm wondering? ¿When do I have to use the DateWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `DateWidget` when you want to override the date format used in the row entry.

It is optional:  if you don't use `DateWidget` then the logic will still use `DateWidget` behind the scenes, but will rely on the format you have declared in [`settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#date-input-formats).  I expect this is why it is working when you remove `widget=DateTimeWidget()`

Looking at your original code, notice how the declaration for `widget` has a `Field` declaration, which is obviously incorrect.  I think it would work ok if you corrected this.

```py
    start_date = fields.Field(
        attribute='start_date',
        widget=fields.Field(
            attribute='start_date',
            column_name='start_date',
            widget=widgets.DateWidget('%d/%m/%Y'))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

So yes, the problem was using the widget=widgets.DateWidget for date fields.
I deleted that part of the resource leaving it like this. And it work.
So, this way works.

```
class retailResource(ModelResource):
    client = fields.Field(
        column_name='client',
        attribute='client',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Client, 'name')
    )
    country = fields.Field(
        column_name='country',
        attribute='country',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Country, 'name')
    )
    catalogue_type = fields.Field(
        column_name='catalogue_type',
        attribute='catalogue_type',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(CatalogueType, 'name')
    )
    currency_in_report = fields.Field(
        column_name='currency_in_report',
        attribute='currency_in_report',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Currency, 'iso3_code')
    )
 class Meta():
        model = RetailPrice
        fields = ('id','client', 'country', 'catalogue_type','quality','gross_retail_price',
                  'currency_in_report','reported_as','start_date','end_date','comments',)
        export_order = ['id','client', 'country', 'catalogue_type','quality','gross_retail_price',
                  'currency_in_report','reported_as','start_date','end_date','comments']
        import_id_fields = ('id',)
```